# Rewind a stream, both ifstream as well as strstream

Tags: c++, c++98

I want to write a HEX file reader. It should support two different formats: Intel HEX and a "ROM" file format where each line contains a pair of address and 16 bit hex value. The reader shall identify the format. For that purpose it must read at least some lines to check if it's at least one valid format.

The file stream shall be passed to the reader with a function like:

```
class CHexFile { 
public:
    bool Open(std::istream& stream);
    uint16_t GetChunk(); // Return two bytes of the stream.
private:
    void Validate(std::istream& stream);
};
```

The parameter type is `std::istream` because this allows to prepare a `std::strstream` in a unit tester and pass the stream to the function.

It's possible to detect the stream format and validate the entire stream. But how can I rewind the stream after validation (or format detection) and actually retrieve the data?

Note: I have to use a rather old C++ compiler from 2006 (Paradigm). Therefore I can't use fancy features from C++1x or C++2x.

Comment: Is [std::istream::seekg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) what you're looking for?

Comment: Do you really mean `std::strstream`? That has been deprecated already in the first standard C++98.

Comment: @Galik I would expect that this should do the job. But after getting once at EOF, the `seekg` call doesn't help to get the nextzline.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, unfortunately I must use the outdated compiler. It doesn't provide a `stringstream` implementation.

Comment: _But after getting once at EOF, the seekg call doesn't help to get the nextzline._ For this, the error flags can be cleared: [std::ios::clear()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear).

Comment: Keep examining the documentation for functions that can help you. You can call [std::istream::clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) to get rid of error conditions and eof status.

Comment: I struggle to believe that `std::stringstream` exists since C++11. (I could swear I already used it beforehand.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat: `std::stringstream` existed even back in C++98.  If OP's compiler doesn't have it, they should probably quit their job.  Fortunately the answer is the same for `strstream` as for `stringstream`.

Comment: Did you `#include <sstream>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `stream.clear(); stream.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);`.  That should rewind any stream that can be rewound.  Of course some `istream`s cannot be rewound, such as `std::cin`, so you'll want to check for an error after `seekg()`.

Comment: I got it with this answer. The actual used code is `i.clear(ios::eofbit);  i.seekg(0, ios::beg);` It is important that `seekg` only works if `clear` has been called **before**. You could emphasize the role of the calling order in your answer.